# Push Notification routing using deep links in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, push-notification, deep-linking

I'm currently working on integrating push notifications into my SwiftUI iOS app, and I want to implement a feature where users can be directed to specific views within the app upon tapping on a notification. I've heard about deep linking and using ViewRouter in SwiftUI for navigation purposes, but I'm not entirely sure how to set it up for push notifications.

Any insights or examples demonstrating the implementation of this feature would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

## This is what I did:

**App Delegate:**

```
`class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        registerForPushNotifications()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
    
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        if let fcm = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
            Singleton.shared.storeString(value: fcm, in: .fcmToken)
           // print("FCM", fcm)
        }
    }
}`
```

**Notification Manager:**

```
`@MainActor
class NotificationManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published private(set) var hasPermission = false
    
    init() {
        Task{
            await getAuthStatus()
        }
    }
    
    func request() async{
        do {
            try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
            await getAuthStatus()
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func getAuthStatus() async {
        let status = await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().notificationSettings()
        switch status.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized, .ephemeral, .provisional:
            hasPermission = true
        default:
            hasPermission = false
        }
    }
}`
```